# Best stereo correspondence algorithm in opencv

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

Well, I have got a stereo setup where it computes the disparity of stereo image pairs using SGBM(Semi-global block matching), BM(Block matching) and Variational matching algorithm using the OpenCV library. But the disparities are not so good as that of the ground truth disparities.

All I wanted to know is, whether opencv provides any function or a program that could compute the ground truth disparity. As per some papers like  "A Taxonomy and Evaluation of Dense Two-Frame Stereo Correspondence Algorithms" by Daniel Scharstein and Richard Szeliski says that Belief Propagation algorithm is the best stereo correspondence algorithm.

Is there any existing code that computes disparities using graph-cut algorithm or belief propagation algorithm in opencv.

Comment: by definition, "ground truth" is not a computed answer.  I think you just want better performance, which the following answers address.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there is in OpenCV, but you do have alternatives. There is C++ code available, and it wouldn't be hard to make it interact with OpenCV:

- In the [Middlebury stereo](http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/code/) website that include graph cut and
  belief propagation for stereo
- There is also Graphcut code from the
  [University of Western Ontario](http://vision.csd.uwo.ca/code/) which is really good.

Comment: If you go to evaluation you can see that the "TSGO" algorithm is the best one, I can't find any information about it though

Answer (score 2):

I think Semi Global Block Matching algorithm by Hirshmuller is one of the best stereo correspondence algorithm.

This algorithm is provided in OpenCV library.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCV implementation of belief propagation is only offered for GPU ([CUDA](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#gpu-stereobeliefpropagation) and [OpenCL](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/camera_calibration_and_3D_reconstruction.html#ocl-stereobeliefpropagation)), not for CPU implementations. They also have the constant space variant of believe prop.

The Middlebury website keeps an updated state of the art on these algorithms, so keep an eye for new entries.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, TSGO is not open sourced, and its article("Accurate Stereo Matching by Two-Step Energy Minimization") is not free either. Has anyone evaluated it?

There is an opencv implementation for GraphCut one and seems quite good, it deserves a try. http://daily-tech.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/06/25/233203